# FileCache vs Session in php

Tags: php, session, caching

Session or FileCache ? Which one is better to use ?

For example when a user logged in, I want to save some data like username, password, id, details, etc. as long as he didn't logout.

I can save this data serialized in some file. and also I can save it in session.

What should I do ?

Comment: Session is most likely better because the handling is automatic. However you NEVER want to put the password or password hash in the session or in your file cache if you go that route. Just store the user_id and/or username and a status.

Comment: Use a database. If I had to choose between the 2 options, I'd go with session.

Comment: @Dave My system makes a login license for each successful login. I thought database makes view process slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File or session cache are so similar, because sessions also written in files, but in fact session are more practical and easier to use, my prefer is Memory Cache, Like Mysql Memory Engine or APCU. just try once.

Answer (score 2):

Save it in a session. It's stored in memory, faster and generally more secure than a file.
Usually you wouldn't store a password in a session as it will be removed once the user leaves the website. Passwords are usually stored in a database sometimes in files but passwords should always be encrypted. Use md5($password.$email) or something similar.
The json data format makes this quite simple.

```
$user['temp_password'] = md5($user['password'].$user['email']);
$user['id'] = 45;
file_put_contents('user_settings.json',json_encode($user));
```

Comment: You mean `hashed`, and not with `md5`.

Answer (score 1):

The best performing solution would be to use the Session, setting your session save_handler to memcached.

First, install memcached

```
apt-get install memcached
apt-get install php5-memcache
```

Then, edit your php.ini to write to memcached instead of file

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path    = "tcp://localhost:11211"
```

Finally

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart
```

Then, when you read and write to/from `$_SESSION` it will be using Memcached

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately windows is installed on my server. I didn't find dll file of this extension and also I couldn't compile it in vc++ myself. :-(

Comment: Ah, I see.  Your question didn't mention that you're on Windows.  I'll still leave this answer here for people on Linux.

Comment: You mean it's not possible to use Memcache on windows :-( ... Thank you steven

Comment: I mean that I'm not familiar enough with PHP on Windows to provide you much help.